# How to access class Directive

Tags: angular, typescript

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
  static test: number = 5;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  highlight(color: string) {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}
```

Granted the above code, my question is what happens if there is nowhere `myHighlight` attribute which will oblige Angular to create an instance of `HighlightDirective` class. My guess is that `HighlightDirective` class itself (not some instance) is created. Am I right? If yes how may I access the class

Answer (score 0):

The notion of "create a class" is a little bit confusing. If your code gets transpiled to EcmaScript5, then if will look smth like this (simplified):

```
var HighlightDirective = (function() {
  function HighlightDirective(el) {
    this.el = el;
  }
  HighlightDirective.test = 5;
  HighlightDirective.prototype.highlight = function() {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
  };
  return HighlightDirective;
)();
```

So, in terms of "class creation" - it's no different that defining a function.

Now, when you require a file that has this class - the function gets created in JS runtime.

Up until now there has been no Angular.

I'm no Angular dev, but I assume that the framework does not create an instance of the directive unless there is a need for that.

As to "how Angular associates directive on an element with this very class" - you can take a look at `angular` source code. This "how" question is too broad for SO format